# Generate complete iso date time representation strings with fraction and timezone

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, iso8601

I want to print an ISO 8601 conforming string of the form of the 
complete date time representation as in ISO

> 4.3.2 Complete    representations

*1985-04-12T10:15:30Z* combined with

> 4.2.2.4 Representations   with    decimal fraction

as *23:20:50,5*

combined as allowed in

> 4.3.3 Representations other   than    complete

as in the form of **19850412T101530,42+04** or **1985-04-12T10:15:30.32Z**

with boost date time using the current (wall clock), but I am not even understanding how to print a simple date time string of the current time by using the boost documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to print "*current (wall clock)*" but your example says "*1985*" ?...

The following will print *current time* in ISO format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

    std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(now) << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2019-04-26T07:52:34.533296
```

Note: ISO time is always in UTC timezone, so you can just append the "Z" (Zulu) suffix to it.

For more details refer to the [Posix_time documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

Comment: 1985 is used in the examples in the ISO :/)  However your answer is almost right, but is wrong/ incomplete since it misses the timezone designator which if omitted would mean local time and not UTC. (So the strings of your code are plain wrong) (The zone designator is empty if use is made of local time in accordance with 4.2.2.2 through 4.2.2.4, it is 
the  UTC  designator  [Z]  if  use  is  made  of  UTC  of  day  in  accordance  with  4.2.4  and  it  is  the 
difference-component  if  use  is  made  of  local  time  and  the  difference  from  UTC  in  accordance  with 
4.2.5.2.)

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger - that's how Boost Posix Time is specified. `to_iso_extended_string` "*Convert to form YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS,fffffffff*". Since you know you're working with UTC time, all you need to do is to append the UTC designator to it yourself. Or better yet, use the [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library, which will simplify migration to the C++20 [std::chrono::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/format) later.